# curl_multi_exec - Stop all calls when one completes

Tags: php, curl-multi

Is it possible to cancel all running calls in curl_multi when one completes successfully? It seems as though curl_multi waits until all processes have finished before finishing the script, but this could be my own perception. I'm attempting to call a single URL with many open connections. The URL will process the requests as fast as possible and when the first one returns I want to close remaining connections and continue with the rest of the calling script.

```
$outArr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();
$curl_arr = array();

$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$std_options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5);

for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    //set custom URL so we can see which one completed.
    $std_options[CURLOPT_URL] = $url.'/sub_proc.php?somearg='.$somearg.'&tlimit='.$tlimit.'&i='.$i;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$std_options);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $ch);
}

do {
    while(($execrun = curl_multi_exec($master, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    if($execrun != CURLM_OK)
        break;
    // a request was just completed -- find out which one
    while($done = curl_multi_info_read($master)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($done['handle']);
        if ($info['http_code'] == 200)  {
            $output = curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);

            // request successful.  process output using the callback function.
            $out = json_decode($output);
            $outArr = $out['board'];
        $running = false;
        break;
        //I want the code above to break all processing requests and 
        //continue with the script outside of this loop.
        } else {
            // request failed.  add error handling.
        }
    }
} while ($running);
curl_multi_close($master);

//does not execute until all requests are complete,
//causing timeouts when one failed request takes > 30 seconds
print_r($outArr);
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting question - what happens if you destroy the multi-handle? `$master = NULL; unset($master);`

Comment: I'll try it. The question stems from a recursive brute force n-queens coding challenge. I've gotten my existing code to handle 75 queens in 22 seconds and 550KB memory used, and 100 queens in 77 seconds and 1MB, but I want to get 100 queens in under 30 seconds. To do this I need a near perfect placement in under 30 seconds, which I could get by increasing the number of processes or threads. Since PHP doesn't have multithreading, I can use curl_multi to increase the number of threads. Then I can break the 100 queen barrier.

Comment: You actually don't need any more processes or threads for this, it's easily possible to make a few hundred HTTP requests in a couple of seconds with pure PHP (assuming you have the bandwidth) - I never use `curl_multi_*` though, how confident are you with socket programming? With the use of non-blocking sockets it's possible to do this, and you would get much finer grained control over what happens when - and you would easily be able to abort at any moment because you have absolute control over the underlying sockets, so you can simply close them at will.